# thanks for or thanks to

Tags: gerunds

Thanks for being here or thanks to be there

I think the first one is good not the second one because the expression is "thank for verbing" not "thanks to". I googled but did not find any mentionning thanks to

Answer (score 4):

In your particular case, the correct answer is "thanks for being here".

There are two different idioms: "thanks for" and "thanks to".

"thanks for": You thank someone for doing something.

> Thanks for reading my letter.

"thanks to": Something happens thanks to someone or something, meaning that they cause it to happen.

> Thanks to modern science, the illness is curable.